# Jquery blur event listener only activating once

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(function(){
    $("#TheBody").ready(func1());
    $("#data_box").on("blur", computeStuff());
});
```

Blur is automatically called on once, then never again. I am baffled as to why it only does it once.

Comment: Where is your html code?

Comment: Yeah, we do not know what does `computeStuff()` returns. if `computeStuff` does not returns a function then first time will happen without any onblur action

Comment: I removed the parentheses next to compute stuff, and now it works. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.